# linear regression by using maximum likelihood in R

Tags: r

I estimated linear regression by using maximum likelihood in R. I did regression, put the data into matrices for the MLE procedure, and estimated the model. V1 is the dependent variable. V2-V7 are the independent variables. I used the following code and I got the following error. What should I do to fix it?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that every closing bracket in the line which starts `sum(-1/2)*` has an equivalent opening bracket. All of the `(y-xbetan)^2)` chunks have two closing brackets to each opening one.

I'm not quite sure what you're aiming for, but perhaps `((y-xbetan)^2)` in each case and then a final closing one `)` at the end of the line?